# how to abort a xmlhttprequest before starting a new request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

I got a cgi-script the performs a search according to the query-string it gets submitted.
That works all fine.
But since the search can take some time and the user might start another search. I want the first search to get aborted before a second search is started, but if I insert a `xmlhttp.abort()` at the beginning of my AJAXRequest function the cgi-script doesn't get started at all. 
Can anyone tell me how this could be performed?

Thanks in advance!

and here is the AJAX-code snippet

```
var xmlhttp;
function AJAXRequest()
{

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   window.document.getElementById("resultlist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
var queryString= "from=03-01-2006&to=04-30-2006&pattern=345";
xmlhttp.open("POST","../cgi-bin/search.exe?"+queryString);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("POST","../cgi-bin/search.exe?"+queryString,true);` - actually `true` parameter is not needed because this value is `true` by default.

Comment: @EvgeniyNaydenov I removed the third parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.
I tried to abort a request object that has just been created. The object has to be global. At least that's the only way I see how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, [`XMLHttpRequest.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) is a correct method to use for AJAX request aborting.
In my opinion your problem is more kind of design problem and not technical.
Therefore my suggestion is to review the flow of how the user interacts with your application.
For example, the classical solution is to show the progress bar or spinner and disable the "Search" button while your request is not completed and revert this state on success or error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll think about something like that But is there no way to first abort a active search before starting a new one?(just in case someone entered wrong search information) I just found out that if I use the abort() after send() an send another request the abort works just fine. But if I use the abort() at the beginning of my function it doesn't seem to send the request at all. Do you have any suggestion what is going wrong?

Comment: Documentation by the link I posted says: "Aborts the request if it has already been sent.". So the `abort()` method will not work before `send()`. Therefore you should block user's interface before sending the request and/or use some timeout after the input if you're making something kind of autocomplete.